# Adopting Equatable Protocol for Enum with nested Enum values

Tags: iphone, swift, enums, swift2

Assuming we have this datastructure:

```
enum Vehicle: Equatable {

   enum Car {
       case BMW(Int)
       case Audi(Int)
   }

   enum Bike {
       case Ducatti(Int)
       case Honda(Int)
   }

}
```

that represents various vehicles with their horsepower as their associated value.

I am trying to conform to the `Equatable` protocol in order to be able to perform `Vehicle` equivalence with no success.

I am trying with:

```
func ==(a: Vehicle, b: Vehicle) -> Bool {
    switch(a, b) {
        case(let Car.BMW(hp1), let Car.BMW(hp2)):
           return hp1 == hp2
        default:
           return false
    }
}
```

but the compiler complains about `invalid pattern`.

So how can we properly conform to the `Equatable` protocol for enums that contain nested enums and associated values?

Comment: It's not clear to me that Vehicle is a valid enum - it certainly has no actual enumeration values - all you're doing is declaring two types...

Comment: It's definitely valid. `let value = Vehicle.Car.BMW(2500)` works fine.

Comment: No, `value` is not a `Vehicle` it's a `Vehicle.Car`. Check its `.dynamicType`

Comment: Uhm... it SHOULD be `Vehicle.Car`, no?

Comment: No, `value`'s *value* should be Vehicle.Car, not its dynamicType...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted, your definition of nested enums does not create cases of `Vehicle`. They just define two types that have nothing to do with each other except their names. What you're trying to do would look like this:

```
enum Vehicle: Equatable {
    enum CarType {
        case BMW(Int)
        case Audi(Int)
    }

    enum BikeType {
        case Ducatti(Int)
        case Honda(Int)
    }

    case Car(CarType)
    case Bike(BikeType)
}

func ==(a: Vehicle, b: Vehicle) -> Bool {
    switch (a, b) {
    case (.Car(.BMW(let hp1)), .Car(.BMW(let hp2))):
        return hp1 == hp2
    default:
        return false
    }
}

let bmw1 = Vehicle.Car(.BMW(1))
let bmw2 = Vehicle.Car(.BMW(1))
let bmw3 = Vehicle.Car(.BMW(2))
bmw1 == bmw2 // true
bmw2 == bmw3 // false
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Vehicle` is not really a valid enum - it certainly does not have any enumeration values. `Car` and `Bike` are simply type declarations, and `Vehicle` is a scope for them. That's why

```
let value = Vehicle.Car.BMW(2500)
```

works - but `value`'s *type* is not a `Vehicle` it's a `Vehicle.Car`.

Comment: I understand your point, and you are right it's not a valid enum in practice since `Vehicle` has no cases. It's declared like that to provide some sorts of namespacing. I've found that in order to perform equality checks, the nested enums like `Car` and `Bike` need to conform to `Equatable` rather than the top level `Vehicle`. That seems to work. However, is there any other, generic way, to make `Vehicle` to conform to `Equatable`? That's the purpose of the questions. Thanks.

Comment: Well, unless `Vehicle` actually has cases, `Equatable` is meaningless, and it is simply a scope. You *could* add cases `case Auto(Car) case Cycle(Bike)`...

Answer (score 1):

the trouble is, that

```
let a = Vehicle.Car.BMW(100)
```

is NOT constant of type Vehicle, but Vehicle.Car ... etc. How would you like to create a variable or constant of Vehicle from your example?

Take in account, that `enum Vehicle` has NO case at all ...