# Convert nested enumeration values into one variable to be passed as function parameters

Tags: ios, swift, enums, swift2, enumeration

I'm not sure if this is possible but I was wondering if it's possible to convert nested enumeration values into a single variable so that they can be passed into a function parameter. Example:

```
enum Food {
  enum Vegetables: String {
    case Spinach    = "Spinach"
    case GreenBeans = "Green Beans"
  }
  enum Fruit: String {
    case Apples    = "Apples"
    case Grapes   = "Grapes"
  }
}

func eat(meal:Food.Vegetables) {
  print("I just ate some \(meal.rawValue)")
}

func eat(meal:Food.Fruit) {
  print("I just ate some \(meal.rawValue)")
}

eat(Food.Fruit.Apples)         //"I just ate some Spinach\n"
eat(Food.Vegetables.Spinach)   //"I just ate some Apples\n"
```

Everything here works as it should but I'm trying to consolidate my two eat functions into 1.  Is there a way to do that?  I figure it would involve a variable that represents all nested variable types that I could pass into one eat function.  Something like:

```
func eat(fruitOrVegetable: Food.allNestedEnumeratorTypes) {
  print("I just ate some \(fruitOrVegetable.rawValue)")
}

eat(Food.Vegetables.GreenBeans)   //"I just ate some Green Beans\n"
eat(Food.Vegetables.Grapes)       //"I just ate some Grapes\n"
```

Is this possible?

Comment: @vadian's answer is good, and you may also want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35505655/adopting-equatable-protocol-for-enum-with-nested-enum-values/35506786#35506786. The important thing to understand is that `Vegetables` and `Fruit` here have no relationship to each other. `Food` is doing absolutely nothing except creating a namespace. Other than the names, this code would be identical if you got rid of `Food`. There is no promise here that every enumeration you happened to put in `Food` would have a `rawValue` property.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I totally understand what you mean about Food in this case.  The only reason I am nesting my enumerator lists in a namespace is purely for organizational purposes because I have so many enumeration lists in my application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a protocol

```
protocol Vegetarian {
  var rawValue : String { get }
}
```

and add it to both enums

```
enum Vegetables: String, Vegetarian { ... }
enum Fruit: String, Vegetarian { ... }
```

Then you can declare `eat`

```
func eat(meal:Vegetarian) {
  print("I just ate some \(meal.rawValue)")
}

eat(Food.Vegetables.GreenBeans)   //"I just ate some Green Beans\n"
eat(Food.Fruit.Grapes)            //"I just ate some Grapes\n"
```